# How to call a function after dynamically created "div" elements are ready

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a meteor application in which I've created some div elements and add them into a modal. When I create them, I position them on the modal by jquery's `.css(left:.., top:..)` method. After that, I call another function which creates lines between these created divs (by using `JSplumb` plug-in).

My problem is that, Jsplumb tries to draw these lines as if my div elements are located on the top left of the modal. In other words, when I call the drawing lines function, it is not aware of the positions of my dynamically created elements on the modal. Therefore, I need to wait until the creation of div elements isfinished.

So, my simplified version of creating div elements function is:

```
ConnectStates.prototype.constructResultSets=function(){
    var sourceResultEntity=$('<div>').attr('id','fooID').addClass('fooClassName');
    var sourceResultSetTitle=$('<div>').addClass('title').text(this.sourceStates[i]);
    var connect=$('<div>').addClass('ep');
    sourceResultEntity.append(sourceResultSetTitle);
    sourceResultEntity.append(connect);
    sourceResultEntity.css({left:($('.sourcePart').width()/2, top:70});
    // source part is a div inside modal-body
    $('.sourcePart').append(sourceResultEntity);
}
```

and then I call draw line function

```
ConnectStates.prototype.connectResultSets=function(){
    // this is only one line, giving id of divs, nothing is important here
}
```

My div's are placed in the correct places, but the line which is supposed to be between them is placed at the wrong position.

Comment: You are appending it too the conenct object, not appending the connect object the the div.

Comment: @Casey sorry I forgot the add it. I've edited my question

Comment: Could you provide an image or a jsfiddle for visual clarity? It's hard to visualize your "div's" and "lines".

Comment: Call the function in the templates onRendered event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand your question correct but why don't you use meteor for that?

1. Create a template with the content of your div

```
    <template name="dynDiv">
      <div id="fooID" class="{{dynClassValues}}" ... ></div>
    </template>
```

2. Insert that template inside an if clause

```
    <#if showDynDiv>
        {{> dynDiv}}
    </if>
```

3. Use Template functions to hook in

```
    Template.dynDiv.onRendered(...
```

Hope that is an option for you

Comment: thank you for reply. How many div do I have will be determined at running time. How could I create a template for each div ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but there isn't "a" limitation in number of templates nor nesting. you may create <template name="foo1" ... "fooX"> and just include via {{> foo1}} {{> foo2}} ... Does that answer your question?

Comment: Maybe this is also a hint: you can use the same div template multiple times with different values given. Have a look at: [this meteor pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Ke9DJnbvtsqjSHJy2/SimpleDataGivenThroughTemplates)